# Accented characters in a @pathVariable not correctly decoded when using swagger-spring-JAVA

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui

I'm using swaggerUI for debbuging my Spring application. In my configuration class I have:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource({ ...})
public class AppConfig{

....

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    filter.setForceEncoding(true);
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new   FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(filter);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
} 

...

}
```

In my controller I have:

```
    public MyreturnedObject myMethod(@ApiParam(value = "myPathParam code of user that needs to fetch the returnedObjects", required = true) @PathVariable final String myPathParam{
...
}
```

When I use swaggerUI with the parameter value ex: **XXÉXX** i get in swaggerUI in the Request URL:

```
https://localhost/myApi/XX%C3%89XX/returnedObjects?...
```

which seems, to me, correctly decoded in UTF-8.
While in my debugger(I'm using RAD and websphere) i get: **XXÃXX**, which is the wrong value.
Can anyone help to pinpoint what I'm doing wrong and tells me how to solve this issue?

**EDIT**

What I have noticed is that the code in the REQUEST URL in swaggerUI for É = C3 89 in UTF but these two parts are somehow decoded as Ã + an empty character, as if it was decoded in UNICODE where C3= Ã and 89 = nothing as shown in this [link](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround that helped me to solve my issue.
In the service called by my controller, I've created a method as follow

```
public String myServiceMethod (String myPathParameter) {
       String encodedUTF8 = null;
       try{
           byte[] utf8 = myPathParameter.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");        
           encodedUTF8 = new String(utf8, "UTF8");
           return encodedUTF8;
       }
       catch(java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e){
         // logger that states that the encoding went wrong
       }
}
```

As I said it is just a workaround so if there a better answer (some spring setup that allow me to do this in a clean way), I'll really appreciate it.